# Using an analog switch to charge/discharge a series of capacitors

Tags: discharge, capacitor-charging, analog-switch

My circuit requirement is very low power consumption to allow/disallow voltage (V1 which is variable 0-5 V) to go through some capacitors (cap1 and cap2) by controlling analog switches (DG2535EDQ) using MCU pins. Also, I need to maintain the switches' status (connected) for about 3 min.

So, I use capacitors c1 and c2 along with diodes to prevent the discharge when MCU is off. Also, I need to discharge c1 and c2 when the cap1's and cap2's switches connected  status are no longer need to be maintained, so that why I use the c1's and c2's switches.

First revision,I did not use comparators, but I ended up with a huge power consumption caused by that the remaining voltage in c1 and c2 was lower than cap1's and cap2's switches power supply (V1), shorting V1 to ground untill V1 becomes less than 1.65 V (which is the switch's minimum voltage operation).

But with this revision (attached), I tried to use a comparator which turned to be a really bad idea, since the leakage from c1's and c2's switches are charging c1 and c2 above the REF (125 V). So, cap1's and cap2's are always connected!

[image]

Any suggestion to maintain cap1's and cap2's switches connected status without introducing a huge power consumption?

Comment: Charging the capacitors from 5 V through the switches' 300 mΩ RDSon will result in a current spike of up to 16.7 A.  Less when the ESR of the capacitors is taken into account but still far far more than the DG2535's absolute maximum peak pulsed current of 0.5 A.

Comment: If you're controlling the switches from an MCU why can't you do the 3 minute delay in software?

Comment: @floppydisk because MCU might be off since it will be powered by harvested energy. So, I want to maintain the switches connected status without using the MCU.

Comment: @Aalsubhi what is 'harvested energy'? You can't keep the switches on if you don't have the power anyway. MCUs in sleep mode can easily get down to microampere levels. Any comtraption you might come up with (using op-amps or 555 timers) would probably consume even more.

Comment: @floppydisk I'm planning to use a solar panel as my power source.

Comment: @vir Thanks for pointing that out. It is a huge consumption. Do have suggestion for alternative switch?

Comment: I would probably use discrete MOSFETs for that.